# Forcing the consistency of $ZF$ from a fragment of $ZF$

Tags: set-theory, forcing, peano-arithmetic

Implicit in the technique of forcing is the following relative consistency result:

> If $\mathfrak M$$\vDash$$T$, and therefore $T$ is consistent (where $\mathfrak M$ is the ground model) then if $\mathfrak M$$[$$G$$]$$\vDash$$T^{'}$,  $T^{'}$ is consistent (since I am  assuming $T$ and $T^{'}$ are first-order theories, this seems an easy consequence of the Goedel completeness theorem).

Also, it is known that class forcings do not always preserve the axioms of $\mathfrak M$$\vDash$$T$ in $\mathfrak M$$[$ $G$ $]$ $\vDash$ $T^{'}$.

The theory $T$ I am specifically interested in is $ZF$ $-$ *Infinity*, that is, $ZF$ with the Axiom of Infinity dropped.

Question:  Is there a class forcing extension of $\mathfrak M$$\vDash$ $ZF$ $-$ *Infinity* such that $\mathfrak M$$[$ $G$ $]$$\vDash$$ZF$ $-$ *Infinity* $+$ *Infinity* (or in the alternative, where $\mathfrak M$$\vDash$$ZF$$-$ *Infinity* $+$ $\lnot$*Infinity* , is there a class forcing producing a forcing extension $\mathfrak M$$[$ $G$ $]$ in which $\lnot$*Infinity* fails)? If there is no such class forcing, show why there cannot be such.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If whoever downvoted my question can give a good reason for the downvote, I will delete the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote,but the question seems unclear to me. My first question concerns "$\mathfrak M\models T$ is consistent." This could mean that it's consistent that $\mathfrak M\models T$, or it could men that $\mathfrak M$ satisfies the formula "$T$ is consistent." Which of those do you mean? Or do you perhaps mean that $\mathfrak M\models T$, and therefore $T$ is consistent? Or something else?

Comment: If you're looking for a proof of the consistency of ZF from the consistency of ZF$-$Infinity, then there is no such proof (at least none that can be formalized in ZFC), because ZF proves the consistency of ZF$-$Infinity. As for proving the consistency, relative to ZF$-$Infinity, of ZF$-$Infinity$+\neg$Infinity, that should be possible by interpreting the latter theory in the former, but I don't see how to bring forcing to bear on that matter.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  I mean, "if $\mathfrak M$$\vDash$$T$, and therefore $T$ is consistent, then $\mathfrak M$$[$ $G$ $]$$\vDash$$T^{'}$, and therefore $T^{'}$ is consistent" (apologies all around for the vagueness of my question--I definitely concede that, given the helpful comments, the question could have been better written).  It was my hope that one could use class forcing to show that _Infinity_ was independent of $ZF$ $-$ _Infinity_  ($ZF$ $-$ _Infinity_ should be able to be proven consistent in $PRA$ $+$ $TI({\epsilon_0})$), but Noah's answer suggests that such a project is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the issues around consistency (which I don't really follow - see Andreas' comments), it seems to me that the mathematical question you're asking is:

> If $M\models ZF-Inf$, can there be a class forcing extension $M[G]$ of $M$ which satisfies full $ZF$?

(Note that $ZF$ and $ZF-Inf+Inf$ are the same thing.)

Let's first think about this in the context of the usual model $V_\omega$ of hereditarily finite sets. We can set up the machinery of class forcing as usual: however, note that *every name is finite*! (Since names are just sets of a certain form in the ground model, and every element of $V_\omega$ is finite.) This means in particular that, no matter what $\mathbb{P}$ and $G$ we pick, in $V_\omega[G]$ every set will be finite. So in particular, $V_\omega[G]$ will not satisfy Inf.

I believe that this generalizes to all models of $ZF-Inf+\neg Inf$+"transitive closures exist" (this is classically proved via Replacement + Infinity), via a similar argument: given a putative name for $\omega$ in the extension, we may recover $\omega$ from its transitive closure in the ground model, contradicting $\neg Inf$ there. I am uncertain as to whether TCE can be dropped here; I don't have much experience with finite set theories. However, I suspect that it can be.

*Note that **set** forcing in finite set theories is trivial: $ZF-Inf+\neg Inf$ proves "in every (set) partial order, the set of minimal elements is dense."*

---

Going back to consistency issues, it sounds like you are trying to prove $Con(ZF-Inf)\implies Con(ZF)$ in a reasonably weak base theory (say, a subtheory of ZF). *This cannot succeed* unless $ZF$ is inconsistent: since $ZF$ *does* prove $Con(ZF-Inf)$, this would imply $ZF\vdash Con(ZF)$.

If that's *not* what you're trying to do, what are you trying to do?

*Incidentally, if you're trying to prove $Con(ZF-Inf)\implies Con(ZF)$ in a possibly stronger base theory, note that this is easily doable: ZF+"there is an inaccessible cardinal" proves $Con(ZF)$, so proves $Con(ZF-Inf)\implies Con(ZF)$. And by the reasoning above, this is the only way to have this occur: if $T$ is a theory containing $ZF$, then $T\vdash Con(ZF-Inf)\implies Con(ZF)$ iff $T\vdash Con(ZF)$.*

Comment: Considering the nature of the comments given, I am willing to delete this question.  Your answer was helpful to me, but if you think your answer will help others, I will not delete.  What do you wish to do?

Comment: Since $ZF$ $+$ "there is an inaccessible cardinal" proves $CON(ZF)$, does the "inacessible cardinal" in question need to be uncountable?  I am given to understand that $\omega$  is countable yet inaccessible.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin If you consider $\omega$ to be inaccessible, then it is *not true* that ZF+"there is an inaccessible" proves Con(ZF). You do indeed need the inaccessible to be uncountable. (Think about the proof - given $\kappa$ inaccessible, we argue that $V_\kappa\models ZF$. But in order for $V_\kappa$ to satisfy $ZF$, it has to satisfy in particular Infinity - so we need $\kappa>\omega$.) My understanding, in fact, is that most authors *do not* consider $\omega$ to be inaccessible, but I could be wrong.

Comment: So in $ZF$ $+$ $AD$ (since $\omega_1$ is inaccessible), one could prove the consistency of $ZF$?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin ZF+AD does indeed prove Con(ZF) (and much, *much* more), but not quite the way you think. In my comment above, by "inaccessible" I meant "**strongly** inaccessible" - in order to conclude that $V_\kappa\models ZF$ in the most direct possible way, we need to show that $V_\kappa$ is closed under powersets. Now, large cardinal notions behave weirdly without choice, but there is no good sense in which $\omega_1$ is strongly inaccessible assuming AD: we will always have a surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\omega_1$. (cont'd)

Comment: And indeed, regardless of whether AD holds, $V_{\omega_1}$ is *never* a model of ZF! This is since every ordinal in $V_{\omega_1}$ is countable, hence has a real code, in $V_{\omega_1}$, so there is no set of all reals. What is true is that if $V\models AD$, then $L_{\omega_1^V}\models ZF$. And this is enough to prove that ZF+AD proves Con(ZF). Note that this is how we show that a *weakly* inaccessible cardinal implies the consistency of ZF: if $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible in $V$, then it is (strongly) inaccessible in $L$, and so $L_\kappa$ (but not necessarily $V_\kappa$) is a model of ZF.

Comment: It might also be interesting to have as the base theory $GPK^{+}_{\infty}$, since Olivier Esser shows in his paper "On the Consistency of a Positive Theory" that the theories $GPK^{+}_{\infty}$ + $AC_{WF}$   and    $KMC$ $+$ _"On is ramifiable"_ are mutually interpretable ($AC_{WF}$ is the axiom of choice defined on all well-founded sets, $KMC$ is Kelly-Morse with the Axiom of Global Choice, On is the class of all ordinals, and _"On is ramifiable"_  is defined as follows:  A class of $KMC$ is _On_-finite iff it is a set, _On_-infinite iff not.  _"On is ramifiable"_   means "Every _On_-infinite

Comment: (cont.) tree with _On_-finite levels has an _On_-infinite branch".).  Since it is known that $KM$ proves $CON(ZF)$,  $GPK^{+}_{\infty}$ $+$ $AC_{WF}$ should prove $CON(ZFC)$.   Since  Esser also states in his paper that, "...The arguments of [M. Forti and R. Hinnion in their paper, "The consistency problem for positive comprehension principles." (J. Symbolic Logic 54, (1989), 1401-1418--my comment]  and [M. Forti  and F. Honsell in their paper, "Models of selfdescriptive set theories".  In:  _Partial Differential Equations and the Calculus of Variations, Essays in Honor of Enni DeGiorgi, I_

Comment: (cont.) (F. Colombini et al, eds.), Birkhauser, Boston 1989, pp. 473-518--my comment also] [prove] that the hyperuniverses $N_{\kappa}$ ($\kappa$ being a strongly inaccessible, weakly compact cardinal) satisfy $GPK^{+}_{\infty}$...", he seemingly implies that $GPK^{+}_{\infty}$ is itself consistent.  If so, the consistency of $KMC$ (and consequently the consistency of $ZF$ and $ZFC$) follows.  On the surface, this seems to be interesting, but I'll bet if one demands more rigor, the claim that $N_{\kappa}$, (where $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccessible, weakly compact cardinal) satisfies

Comment: (cont.) $GPK^{+}_{\infty}$ serves to prove its consistency will soon begin to unravel (as arguments of this type usually do....)